How to debug Chalice route handlers in VSCode
Using the following launch.json, I'm able to hit breakpoints in the module level code, but not in route-handlers.
launch configuration (the last three lines may not be needed, but are just some things I've tried)
{
    "name": "Chalice: Local",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/bin/chalice",
    "args": [
        "local",
        "--no-autoreload",
    ],
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "justMyCode": false,
    "subProcess": true,
    "gevent": true
}

app.py:
...
app = Chalice(app_name="something") # breakpoint here does hit
...

@app.route("/{cluster}", methods=["POST"])
def deploy_pods(cluster):
    print(cluster) # breakpoint here doesnt hit (but I can see the print happening)


this issue could be the reason why there is no invocation. I tried it with your code. In the deploy_pods, as you description, can't hit the breakpoint. I tried invoking deploy_pods outside of the method and passing in the arguments, and the breakpoint was hit.


The function gets called when I actually call the endpoint over http. i think the problem is that it is in a different process. Calling it from the module level doesnt really make sense because there’s no request payload then.

You can try it with import debugpy when you call it. Then use the breakpoint where it is called at the module level to see if it is effectively called.
